Sort combined data from different sheets + columns in 'main' sheet
I have a spreadsheet with 4 tabs. Sheet 4 will serve as a 'main' sheet with the combined data from sheets 1 tot 3. The following formule is working van for the imported data.
=SORT(
    ARRAYFORMULA({
         IMPORTRANGE("sheet1URL","Sheet1!A2:E");
         IMPORTRANGE("sheet2URL","Sheet2!A2:E");
         IMPORTRANGE("sheet3URL","Sheet3!A2:E")
,1,FALSE}))

The formula sort on column A, which is a date. However, in the 'main' sheet, people can fill in column F and G manually. Those columns are not included in the sort function because they are not imported, but manualy filled in.
How can I include this so the entire row gets sorted?

Doing what you want in the same formula would likely result in the Error In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows. This is an expected behavior since the 4th sheet would have 7 columns of data, whereas the others would only have 5.

Instead, I'd recommend that you create another tab in the spreadsheet and use that data for sorting. The way I did it was that I used the QUERY function to extract the data from the 3 sheets to the 4th one, created a new tab, and used the SORT function on it, referencing the data in the 4th sheet.
